# How to pass numeric value from a link to a script on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am using a Facebook gallery plugin to display my album on my gallery page, but i want to control with links the albums to select.

onlyAlbum: 875640352512391, this is the number of the album to load, so i have to some how pass the numbers from my menu to this setting.
I hope someone can help.

```html
MENU:
      <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
       <h1 class="memberstitle"><span>The Gallery</span></h1>
        <ul id="nav">
          <li><a href="#" id="here">Gallery</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" target="gallery">photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="gallery">photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="gallery">photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="gallery">photos</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Back to home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

JavaScript:
<div class="fb-album-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".fb-album-container").FacebookAlbumBrowser({
            account: "natgeo",
            accessToken: "***************|***************",
            onlyAlbum: "10150310813623951",
            showComments: true,
            commentsLimit:3,
            showAccountInfo: true,
            showImageCount: true,
            showImageText: true,
            shareButton: false,
            albumsPageSize: 0,
            photosPageSize: 0,
            lightbox: true,
            photosCheckbox: true,
   pluginImagesPath: "../src/",
            likeButton: true,
            shareButton: true,
            addThis:"ra-52638e915dd79612",
```

Comment: Is that your real access token?

Comment: It'll be in the source of his page anyhow.

Comment: So your app is not named “Album Browser JQuery local” …?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean i have no App!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and fix this up, as your code snippet was incomplete, but you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadGallery('10150310813623951');
  $('a[target=gallery]').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).data('gallery-id');
    loadGallery(id);
    return false;
  });
});

function loadGallery(id) {
  alert('Loading gallery #'+id);
/*  $(".fb-album-container").FacebookAlbumBrowser({
    account: "natgeo",
    accessToken: "775908159169504|cYEIsh0rs25OQQC8Ex2hXyCOut4",
    onlyAlbum: id,
    showComments: true,
    commentsLimit: 3,
    showAccountInfo: true,
    showImageCount: true,
    showImageText: true,
    shareButton: false,
    albumsPageSize: 0,
    photosPageSize: 0,
    lightbox: true,
    photosCheckbox: true,
    pluginImagesPath: "../src/",
    likeButton: true,
    shareButton: true,
    addThis: "ra-52638e915dd79612",
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <h1 class="memberstitle"><span>The Gallery</span></h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" id="here">Gallery</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="gallery" data-gallery-id='12345'>photos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="gallery" data-gallery-id='44444'>photos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="gallery" data-gallery-id='66666'>photos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="gallery" data-gallery-id='88888'>photos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Back to home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="fb-album-container"></div>
```

Comment: Having tried you code it still does not work, i think it may have something to do with onlyAlbum: id, would it still read as if it was just a number?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to just parse a string and put that somewhere in your html? Or are you wanting to scan your HTML and use something from that to populate your js?

If you want to parse the HTML, you should look into [jquery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/). Or if you want to insert it into the HTML from the JS, check out [DOM Insert](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

Comment: Just wanting to parse a value from the click event of the link to the script but have tried your suggestion i don't think the script likes "id", maybe it will only work with a numeric value.

Comment: Using jQuery: $('.link').click(function(){ // some code with this. being a main focus of it. Or using parent/child